# Is there a way to check if the min and max values of a table are equal to each other in SQL/Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, clause

Say a column is:

```
Price  
$3.00  
$3.00
```

The min and max would be equal. Is there a way to check for that in the WHERE clause?

Comment: select case when max(price) = min(price) then 'dosomething' else 'dosomething' end as 'something'

Comment: Ricky, how are you getting on with the below answers? They look helpful. It is customary here to vote on, accept, or reply to answers shortly after they come in.

Comment: With regret, downvoted (see above).

Answer (score 1):

There is a hundred years old `HAVING` for filtering by aggregates.

```
SELECT 1
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
HAVING MAX(PRICE) = MIN(PRICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t(price) AS ( VALUES
  (3.00),
  (3.00)
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN max(price) = min(price) THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
  END
FROM t;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a way of doing that in MS SQL, I guess that should help you for Postgres somehow:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table HAVING MAX(Price) = MIN(Price))
    PRINT 'Equal'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not equal'
```

Another way inspired in Dmitry's answer:

```
IF ((SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(Price) = MIN(Price) THEN 1 END FROM Table) = 1)
    PRINT 'Equal'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not equal'
```